# AWS s3 Listing Object Keys Using PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm working on Listing Object Keys Using PHP using AWS s3.

I have the bucket setup with one test file loaded:

[Screenshot of my s3 bucket with one test file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHj1U.png)

Here is the reference that I'm using from AWS documentation:

[AWS ListingObjectKeysUsingPHP webpage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingObjectKeysUsingPHP.html)

Here is the code that I'm using from the page:

```php
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;

$bucket = 'apollos-integrations-public';

// Instantiate the client.
$s3 = new S3Client([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region'  => 'us-east-1'
]);

// Use the high-level iterators (returns ALL of your objects).
try {
    $objects = $s3->getPaginator('ListObjects', [
        'Bucket' => $bucket
    ]);

        //var_dump($objects);

    echo "Keys retrieved!" . PHP_EOL;
    foreach ($objects as $object) {
        echo $object['Key'] . PHP_EOL;
    }
} catch (S3Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
}

// Use the plain API (returns ONLY up to 1000 of your objects).
try {
    $result = $s3->listObjects([
        'Bucket' => $bucket
    ]);

    echo "Keys retrieved!" . PHP_EOL;
    foreach ($result['Contents'] as $object) {
        echo $object['Key'] . PHP_EOL;
    }
} catch (S3Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
}

?>
```

When I execute this PHP script, it simply returns: "Keys retrieved!" without the test file listed.  It should list the files in the folder.

When I add a "var_dump($objects);"  (commented in the script, so when I uncomment it), then it returns a lot of data for the object as shown in this screenshot:

[image for the object var dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELY4N.jpg)

For some reason, this part of the code provided by Amazon is not working:

```php
    foreach ($objects as $object) {
        echo $object['Key'] . PHP_EOL;
    }
```

Why isn't this code provided by AWS working?

Shouldn't the key and secret be required?

Please help

Comment: You should have pasted the `var_dump` result as text rather than a picture - you would have noticed there is no `Key` element inside this object. If you try to visit `http://apollos-integrations-public.s3.amazonaws.com/` you will get an XML document where the files are listed with their keys.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem was most likely caused by PHP AWS SDK not being able to get the credentials from your environment variables --> the credentials are either taken from environment variables, or you should specify them directly in your code like this:

```
// Instantiate the client.
$credentials = new Aws\Credentials\Credentials('<KEY>', '<SECRET>');
$s3 = new S3Client([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region'  => 'us-east-1',
    'credentials' => $credentials
]);
```

(Replace '`<KEY>`' and '`<SECRET>`' with your credentials.). You can find the whole script bellow.

More information can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/guide_configuration.html

Whole script (notice first two rows, where I enabled debugging info. This will show you error messages in case there is some problem - like in this case with the credentials):

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;

$bucket = 'apollos-integrations-public';

// Instantiate the client.
$credentials = new Aws\Credentials\Credentials('<KEY>', '<SECRET>');

$s3 = new S3Client([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region'  => 'us-east-1',
    'credentials' => $credentials
]);

// Use the high-level iterators (returns ALL of your objects).
try {
    $objects = $s3->getPaginator('ListObjects', [
        'Bucket' => $bucket
    ]);

    echo "Keys retrieved!" . PHP_EOL;
    foreach ($objects as $object) {
        echo $object['Key'] . PHP_EOL;
    }
} catch (S3Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
}

// Use the plain API (returns ONLY up to 1000 of your objects).
try {
    $result = $s3->listObjects([
        'Bucket' => $bucket
    ]);

    echo "Keys retrieved!" . PHP_EOL;
    foreach ($result['Contents'] as $object) {
        echo $object['Key'] . PHP_EOL;
    }
} catch (S3Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
}
```

BTW. this is the error message which you would see if you enable debugging info:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Aws\Exception\CredentialsException: Error retrieving credentials from the instance profile metadata server.
```

Hopefully you find it helpful.

Comment: @ApollosEasy: Did this answer helped?

Comment: Yes, this did answer the question.  Unfortunately the project got cancelled and sorry I didn't get back to you sooner.